# Class members in Fragment become null after Home button press and wait

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-lifecycle

### Problem Description

Application which I'm writing has 3 Fragments. Main Fragment Activity has a Search Box with Search button when I press on a Search button the function below is called:

```
Fragments.values()[tabControl.getCurrentItem()].getFragment().search(tv.getText().toString(), MainActivity.this.getApplicationContext());
```

Everything works Okay until I press HOME button wait for 30 minutes and relaunch application, after I press Search button in `FragmentYellowPages` Fragment application crashes on the lines

```
lvYellowPages.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

as `lvYellowPages` in this case is null, but In a logs I can see that `onCreateView` function is called. Can you please help me, I can share my code with you.

---

#### FragmentPagerAdapter

```
public class FragmentAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    Fragments[] mFragments;

    public FragmentAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    
        mFragments = Fragments.values();
    }

    public enum Fragments {
    
        Favorites(App.getStringByResId(R.string.favorites), new FragmentFavorites()),
        Categories(App.getStringByResId(R.string.categories), new FragmentCategories()),
        YellowPages(App.getStringByResId(R.string.yellow_pages), new FragmentYellowPages());
    
        Fragments(String title, BaseListFragment fragment) {
            this.mTitle = title;
            this.mFragment = fragment;
        }
        
        String mTitle;
        BaseListFragment mFragment;
    
        public String getTitle() {
            return mTitle;
        }
            
        public BaseListFragment getFragment() {
            return mFragment;
        }
    };

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mFragments[position].getTitle();
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragments[position].getFragment();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragments.length;
    }
};
```

---

#### List Fragment

```
public class FragmentYellowPages extends BaseListFragment {

    final static String TAG = FragmentYellowPages.class.getSimpleName();

    ListView lvYellowPages;
    TextView tvInfo;
    SimpleCursorAdapter scAdapter;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    
        View yellowPagesView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_yellow_pages, container, false);
    
        Log.i(TAG, "onCreateView( )");
    
        tvInfo = (TextView) yellowPagesView.findViewById(R.id.tvYellowPagesInfo);
        lvYellowPages = (ListView) yellowPagesView.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    
        return yellowPagesView;
    
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    
        Log.i(TAG, "onCreate( )");
    
        setRetainInstance(true);

    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    
        Log.i(TAG, "onActivityCreated( )"); 
    }


    @Override
    public void onResume() {    
        super.onResume();
    
        Log.i(TAG, "onResume( )");      
    }

    void updateAdapterOnSearch(final String tts, final String lang) {
        Log.i(TAG, String.format("updateAdapterOnSearch(%s, %s)", tts, lang));
    
        /* Show "Yellow Pages" list view and hide Info text view. */
        lvYellowPages.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        tvInfo.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        /* Some code .... */
    }

    @Override
    public void search(final String tts, final Context context) {
        Log.i(TAG, String.format("search(%s)", tts));
    
        /* If user search for the text. */ 
        if (tts != null && tts.length() != 0) {
            updateAdapterOnSearch(tts, lang);
        }
    }

};
```

### Fragment Layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffffc8"
    android:tag="FRAGMENT_YELLOW_PAGES_TAG" >

    <ListView android:id="@android:id/list"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:visibility="gone"
              android:background="#ffffc8"/>

    <TextView android:id="@+id/tvYellowPagesInfo"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
              android:layout_centerVertical="true"
              android:gravity="center"
              android:padding="5dp"
              android:text="@string/no_companies_were_found"
              android:visibility="gone"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Do you see "onCreateView" Log when relaunching app after Home button press or just when the app is started for the first time?

Comment: @ViToBrothers Just add `mViewPager.setSaveEnabled(false);` in your `onCreate` function. Oh and you do not need to wait 30 minutes to reproduce, get a task killer and kill the app then open it.

Comment: @SherifelKhatib I will try it and let you know. If you will be right please add your comment as an answer in order I can accept it.

Comment: @SherifelKhatib mViewPager.setSaveEnabled(false); doesn't help :( it still crashes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's hard to pinpoint the exact problem but I'm almost sure it has to do with the way you built the adapter for the `ViewPager`.

> Everything works Okay until I press HOME button wait for 30 minutes
>   and relaunch application, after I press Search button in
>   FragmentYellowPages Fragment application crashes

As the `Activity` is in the background(and apparently killed) it will recreate its content when comming back to the foreground. At this point the `ViewPager` will rebuild its content, but its adapter will not call `getItem()` as it has all the data to recreate the previous fragments on it own. So you'll end up with two fragment version, the ones currently visible in the `ViewPager`(so you see the `onCreateView()` being called) and those that are in the `enum`. Those fragments from the `enum` aren't tied to the `Activity` and so the entire callbacks stack isn't run for them, so `onCreateView()` will not be called, which will make your *lvYellowPages* `ListView` `null`.

Btw, this is the first time I've seen the fragments of an adapter being built in a `enum` and I recommend that you avoid this.

The solution is to not reference the fragments of the `ViewPager` outside. Make the `getItem()` method return a `Fragment` instance and if you need to access those fragment there are ways to do it without storing the `ViewPager`'s fragment in lists/enums etc(a quick search on stackoverflow should show you a question about this):

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    switch (position) {
    case 0:
       return new FragmentFavorites();
    case 1:
       return new FragmentCategories();
    case 2:
       return new FragmentYellowPages();
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 3;
}
```

Also:

```
setRetainInstance(true);
```

I wouldn't use this. It doesn't make sense to retain a fragment used by a `ViewPager`(as I don't think you're planing to move it somewhere else) and it will also not protect you from the activity being killed in the background.

Comment: can you please bring an example of how to get fragment :( I search through internet and find  `findFragmentByTag` method but then I call it it return null :(. I change my code in way which you say, but now I can't get fragment.

Comment: @ViToBrothers This helps? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7379165/update-data-in-listfragment-as-part-of-viewpager

Comment: why it's so hard ?? I can't understand how to do that :(

Comment: @ViToBrothers All you need to do is build a tag like `"android:switcher:"+R.id.theIdOfTheViewPager+":"+ position`(where the position is the position in the `ViewPager`, if you programmatically set and id for the ViewPager, use that). This is assuming you still use a `FragmentPagerAdapter`. Did you tried this and the fragment can't be found?